# Why I cant unignore node_modules and lib folder using NETBEANS ang GIT in IONIC project?

Tags: git, netbeans, ionic-framework

I have created IONIC project and develop it using NETBEANS. I want to push it to GIT but folders like **/node_modules** and **/www/lib** are always ignored. Could you tell me why? Here is my .gitignore

> /platforms/
>   /nbproject/

Im wonderig if I need those folders. Could I build (using cloud services like adobe) or import project with no errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sidenote: You shouldn't be pushing binary files, like those in node_modules and lib folders, to your "source" control, since you should be able to recreate those out of your source at any time.*

That being said, if you really need to do it anyway, try using git bash (command line) to see if the files are still being ignored, because Netbeans might be using its own client, which filters files further, after reading your .gitignore file.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance of ionic/cordova framework, but if I want some other person to clone my project, they will be missing the node_modules directory. Wouldn't it be causing troubles?

Comment: Well, just create a script (using npm) to recreate that folder, from the list of referenced packages (most of today's IDEs do it automatically for you, btw) and commit that script to the source control.

Comment: More info here: http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2012/07/29/are-node_modules-in-git-still-necessary-with-npm-shrinkwrap-2/